How do I pass a nullable type to a function that accepts only a non nullable parameter when using early return checks
Say I have the function below that formats a string response back from an API call.
String formatResponse(String text){
    return text.toUpperCase();
}

and I want to use this function in my Flutter component like so.
class _ComponentWithState extends State<ComponentWithState> {
    
    String? serverResponse;
 
    @override
    void initState() {
        ApiController().loadFromServer().then((response){
            setState((){
                serverResponse = response;
            })
        }
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        
        if(serverResponse == null){
            return LoaderComponent();
        }
        return Text(formatResponse(serverResponse)); // This line says String? cant be passed to type String

    }
    
}

This code would raise an error saying that you cant pass a String? to type String.
Which in the case of null saftey makes sense, but this code has an early return to handle the null check.
Is there something im not understanding about null safe design patterns? The code seems logical to me coming from non null safe languages. This example is obviously very trivial, but I think it conveys the issue.
Note:

as a hack (and that's truly what it feels like) ive just been using serverResponse ?? "" but that feels really bad to have to do.


https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#working-with-nullable-fields

@mmcdon20 so the solution is to serverResponse! on the usage of it? or re assign the variable locally?

@mmcdon20 so the ! just tells the compiler that you explicitly checked to make sure this wasnt null? what happens if it runs and is null? does is crash at run time?

You would get a runtime exception if you use ! on a value that is actually null. Using a local variable is safer.

@mmcdon20 awesome. thanks for your answer. i read through that page but the one sentence about 'slapping' an ! on it i didnt see. lol

The ! is called the non-null assertion operator if you want to read more about it.

return switch(serverResponse) {
  null => LoaderComponent(),
  final v => Text(formatResponse(v)),
};


This one is interesting. A little too close to ternay for what the actually application is, but i like the idea.

Because your string is in the class and not inside the function the analyzer can't infer the string is not null even after the if, because your other methods can change it.
Try reading it into a variable inside your method and use that var
final String? response = server response

if (response == null) {
    return LoaderComponent();
}
return Text(formatResponse(response)); // it won't throw a possible null


So Dart will infer its nullness only in the local function scope? That makes sense.

It cannot infer a getter as non-nullable.  You don't have local getters, so local scope never has this problem.
